# AWS CloudFront showing access denied to S3 bucket using cloud front?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

when i am reloading web cloud front shows

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>CE8DFE7BB8ACC609</RequestId>
<HostId>
8uaOk0M3qYhtyyQ1vP/EjOLuL7pRx81cv9hablImuUsWBSdfxxA5eDKmBdLS+FdQEEtd2CU2rLU=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Can you access the same object directly via S3 (with the only thing different in the URL being the domain name)? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is that cloudfront itself showing you the error message? Or is that what you are seeing when you load a website referencing the cloudfront distribution?